# I can't access login page

Tags: admin, login, htaccess

I was copying my web from live host, but when I want to access admin dashboard, the url can't be accessed

The url is changed to be like this : 
http://backstagewhisp.local/wp-admin/backstagewhisp.local/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fbackstagewhisp.local%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

I changed to http://backstagewhisp.local/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fbackstagewhisp.local%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 , but still can't get to the login page.

I changed my .htaccess to be like this, but I'm still getting the error

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ 
http://backstagewhisp.local/$4
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

can someone give me some advice to fix my error, thanks

Comment: i think this url not working  http://backstagewhisp.local/

Comment: @vikrantzilpe that's my local domain

Comment: still error, i was try to remove what you say, and change the rewrite base, but error still same

Comment: please check doc : https://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble

Comment: please try to add wp-config.php file define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );

Answer (score 0):

**Reset Plugins Manually:**

There might be an issue with the plugins. As you can't get into admin, you have to reset them manually. Just follow these steps mentioned [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-admin-page-error-this-site-cant-be-reached-unexpectedly-closed/). If it solves the problem, activate the plugins one by one to find the defective one.

**Activate Default Theme Manually:**

If resetting plugins doesn't fix your issue, then you can try following these steps:

1. Get access to your server via FTP.
2. Head to to /wp-content/themes/
3. Rename the directory of theme that is currently being used. It will
   activate the default theme. As a result, you can get rid of the
   issue caused by the previous theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error showing for your .htaccess code. Which guidance do you follow to create this, if you share, it will help. Or use this code

`# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /   # Use the correct base path for your installation
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`


#END WordPress

it may be work.